# Clion: Target "[NAME]" not found

Tags: build, cmake, project, clion

When trying to build my project, I see this in the build configurations (it pops up):

[image: Run/Debug Configrations window, with error message]

"LUCID" is the name of my project. I think it all built fine yesterday, but now after only restating I'm getting this:

> **Error:** Target 'LUCID (LUCID)' not found.

The "Target" dropdown only has that one item in it (and also the "Build All" option). I do have `project(LUCID)` and `add_executable(LUCID ${SOURCE_FILES})` in CMakeLists.txt, as was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801836/setting-build-target-in-clion), although the situation is slightly different.

So, why am I getting this error and what do I do to fix it?

Another thing to note is that all the file names that should be part of my project and are specified in `set(SOURCE_FILES ...)` are greyed out in the CLion file browser, which they should not be.

Comment: Can you copy you cmake here ?

Comment: @Waxo Sure, here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/RzkMFnyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may put all you `include_directory` before `add_executable`.
And use only the `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)` futher more if you use the REQUIRED keyword you don't have to use the `if (lib_FOUND)` [source here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for).

You CMake may look like something like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(LUCID)

set(EXEC_NAME LUCID)

MESSAGE("a test message")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

find_package (Box2D REQUIRED)
find_package (opengl REQUIRED)
find_package (SDL2 REQUIRED)

set(INCLUDE_DIR
    sinclude
    sinclude/3rdparty
    uniheader
    D:/freetype-2.5.3/GnuWin32/include
    ${BOX2D_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES
    ssrc/Cam.cpp
    #...
    #Lots of source and header files in the same form
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")


message(STATUS "Boaorm")

add_executable(${EXEC_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${BOX2D_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

For SDL i used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850472/how-to-use-sdl2-and-sdl-image-with-cmake), but i don't like to use `${PROJECT_NAME}` for executable name (you can choose what you prefer anyway)

**Edit :**
Multiple target_link_libraries are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254594/cmake-splitting-independent-libraries-into-different-target-link-libraries-ca)
The problem with the old cmake was the `include_directories` after the `add_executable` and the common toolchain is include -> compile -> link then i just follow this logic.

Comment: Thank you, this looks way cleaner. However, would you care to explain why and which part fixes the problem with the missing target? Also, `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")` can't be moved below the find_package calls, because they need it to find the `FindBox2D.cmake` etc. files.

Comment: ok i fixed the position of `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")` i've never used this. And added some explanations. Is this working now ?

Comment: Yes, this fixes my problem (I still have build issues, but that's another story).  And thank you for the clarification, I now understand that it was the includes that were the issue.

Comment: I think I should add a note that I'm not sure it was this that solved my problem. I seems this problem randomly appears or disappears upon restarting Clion. I can't get a grasp over this...

Comment: In this case it's mostly a problem with clion i can suggest you to report a bug to them : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A+CLion. I hope they can fix it for you fast.

Answer (score 3):

Reset cache and reload project!

```
Tools > CMake > Reset Cache and Reload Project
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this weird bug yesterday. My `CMakeLists.txt` is correct (because I can build the project though the terminal).

The end of my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
add_executable(assignment-1 main.cpp ${SOURCES})
add_library(libassignment-1 STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

I removed the CMake cache directory, commented out `add_library()` and reloaded it. Just like that, CLion can now find the `assignment-1` executable. Then I uncommented the last line. All the configurations are still fine.